# Error creating PivotTable via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using the macro recorder, I generated the following code to add a PivotTable:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Step 1!R1C1:R30750C34", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Pivot Table 2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Pivot Table 2").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("STOCK NUMBER")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("DUO QTY"), "Sum of DUO QTY", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Excess"), "Sum of Excess", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Cann"), "Sum of Cann", xlSum
```

I then made one change, so that the row number for the sourceData would be dynamic rather than fixed:

```
Sheets("Step 1").Activate
Step1Rows = Sheets("Step 1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Step 1!R1C1:R" & Step1Rows & "C34", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Pivot Table 2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
```

When I run this code, I get a run-time error 5, invalid procedure call or argument.  Upon further investigation, I get the same error if I try to run the recorded code.  I initially thought it had to do with the hard-coded tableName, but I tried changing that and I still get the same run-time error.  Kinda at a loss as to how to proceed right now, so if anyone can spot something wrong or offer suggestions it would be most appreciated

Comment: what version of Excel are you using ? not familiar with `DefaultVersion:=6` , see MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpivottableversionlist.aspx

Comment: Tried changing it to `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15` and got the same error.  On a lark tried `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion16` and got a variable undefined error....

Comment: i prefer setting variables for sheets and ranges, it's safer later not to get errors (at least eliminate this factor when troubleshooting). There is a great example at: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=147:create-an-excel-pivot-table-report-using-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues here.

First: The macro recorder does something wrong with the sheet name in `TableDestination:= "Pivot Table 2!R1C1"`. Since it has spaces within the name it must be `TableDestination:= "'Pivot Table 2'!R1C1"`. Note the name within single quotes.

Second: You cannot create a new pivot table in a cell range which already contains a pivot table. So either you must delete the old pivot table first or you must update the already present pivot table.

If the sheet "Pivot Table 2" only contains this pivot table and nothing else, then the simplest thing would be:

```
Step1Rows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Step 1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Table 2").Cells.Delete

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Step 1!R1C1:R" & Step1Rows & "C34", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'Pivot Table 2'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Comment: The single quotes were the issue...can't believe I didn't see that.  The macro creates the sheet "Pivot Table 2" and then adds the pivot table, so there's no issue with that...but good to know.  Thanks!